# How to check if the following series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm taking a Calculus course and I'm completely horrible at it. I'm really bad at math, so please, bear with me. I have the following series:

[The series to check for convergence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ejsg5h2lljl)

The limit of this series is zero right? Is this enough to tell it converges? Or does it diverge?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the limit of the series' sequence is zero...yes, it is, and this is a *necessary* but not sufficient condition for the series' convergence, so no: it is not enough* for either poissibility

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{2n^2+1}{n^4+3}\le\frac{3n^2}{n^4}=3\cdot\frac1{n^2}\;\ldots\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

The general term of the series is no bigger than some constant times $1/n^2,$ so it converges by the comparison test (of course, Wolfram Alpha tells you what the sum is, too).

Comment: BTW, clicking on "full result" in that page of WA one gets an awfully mistaken page...another huge mistake of WA since the series clearly converges.

Comment: @DonAntonio The series is index on $j$, the input diverges.

Comment: Good catch, @GitGud ! I completely oversaw that one...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio the mistake is the OP's (and of your reading comprehension) -- look at the term he is summing, and what it is being summed with respect to. Anything peculiar?

Answer (score 1):

You have
$${2n^2 + 1\over n^4 + 3} \sim {2\over n^2}$$
The last is a convergent $p$-series.